# Preventing threaded subprocess.popen from terminating my main script when child is killed?

Tags: multithreading, python-2.7, signals, subprocess, parent-child

Python 2.7.3 on Solaris 10

**Questions**

1. When my subprocess has an internal Segmentation Fault(core) issue or a user externally kills it from the shell  with a SIGTERM or SIGKILL, my main program's signal handler handles a SIGTERM(-15) and my parent program exits. **Is this real? or is it a bad python build?**

**Background and Code**

I have a python script that first spawns a worker management thread.  The worker management thread then spawns one or more worker threads.  I have other stuff going on in my main thread that I cannot block.  My management thread stuff and worker threads are rock-solid.  My services run for years without restarts but then we have this `subprocess.Popen` scenario:

In the run method of the worker thread, I am using:

```
class workerThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self) :
        super(workerThread, self).__init__()
    ...
    def run(self)
        ...
        atempfile = tempfile.NamedTempFile(delete=False)

        myprocess = subprocess.Popen( ['third-party-cmd', 'with', 'arguments'],  shell=False, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=atempfile, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,close_fds=True)
        ...
```

I need to use `myprocess.poll()` to check for process termination because I need to scan the `atempfile` until I find relevant information  (the file may be > 1 GiB) and I need to terminate the process because of user request or because the process has been running too long.  Once I find what I am looking for, I will stop checking the stdout temp file.  I will clean it up after the external process is dead and before the worker thread terminates.  I need the stdin PIPE in case I need to inject a response to something interactive in the child's stdin stream.

In my main program, I set a SIGINT and SIGTERM handler for me to perform cleanup, if my main python program is terminated with SIGTERM or SIGINT(Ctrl-C) if running from the shell.

Does anyone have a solid 2.x recipe for child signal handling in threads? 
ctypes sigprocmask, etc.

Any help would be very appreciated.  I am just looking for an 'official' recipe or the **BEST hack**, if one even exists.

**Notes**

I am using a restricted build of Python. I must use 2.7.3. Third-party-cmd is a program I do not have source for - modifying it is not possible.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Even though I do not have an answer for you, I recommend that you delete most of your 'wall of text.' That will probably scare away potential answerers. At the very least, split it into sections.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Not sure how to edit it and get what I am trying to convey across.

Comment: I edited to your question to help to make it more readable. You don't have to *change* what you wrote, but it is helpful to split it into subsections.

Comment: Also, to help you make others interested in your posts, I recommend that you read [this post about asking good questions](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist.aspx) and [this post about writing great (attractive) titles.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10648/210573)

Comment: thanks for the help.  I am definitely a newbie.  I will check out the post

Comment: 1. Run it using regular python2.7 and/or subprocess32 *for debugging purposes*. See whether the problem stays. 2. Handle signals only in the main thread. 3. You don't need the temporary file, you could use [PIPE to search the subprocess' output](https://gist.github.com/zed/3b4606d811fcf6530795) 4. Spawn the subprocess in the main thread before starting any threads (you could delegate reading its output to another thread if you don't use `select()` or its analogs but leave Popen in the main thread)

Answer (score 1):

There are many things in your description that look strange. First thing, you have a couple of different threads and processes. Who is crashing, who's receinving SIGTERM and who's receiving SIGKILL and due to which operations ?

Second: why does your parent receive SIGTERM ? It can't be implicitly sent. Someone is calling kill to your parent process, either directly or indirectly (for example, by killing the whole parent group).

Third point: how's your program terminating when you're handling SIGTERM ? By definition, the program terminates if it's not handled. If it's handled, it's not terminated. What's really happenning ?

Suggestions:

```
    $ cat crsh.c
    #include <stdio.h>

    int main(void)
    {
        int *f = 0x0;

        puts("Crashing");
        *f = 0;
        puts("Crashed");
        return 0;
    }
    $ cat a.py

    import subprocess, sys

    print('begin')
    p = subprocess.Popen('./crsh')
    a = raw_input()
    print(a)
    p.wait()
    print('end')
    $ python a.py 
    begin
    Crashing
    abcd
    abcd
    end
```

This works. No signal delivered to the parent. Did you isolate the problem in your program ?

If the problem is a signal sent to multiple processes: can you use setpgid to set up a separate process group for the child ?

Is there any reason for creating the temporary file ? It's 1 GB files being created in your temporary directory. Why not piping stdout ?

If you're really sure you need to handle signals in your parent program (why didn't you try/except KeyboardInterrupt, for example ?): could signal() unspecified behavior with multi threaded programs be causing those problems (for example, dispatching a signal to a thread that does not handle signals) ?

```
NOTES
     The effects of signal() in a multithreaded process are unspecified.
```

Anyway, try to explain with more precision what are the threads and process of your program, what they do, how were the signal handlers set up and why, who is sending signals, who is receiving, etc, etc, etc, etc, etc.

Comment: Yes.  Your example does work but my problem is much more complex.  Thank you for pointing out that it was confusing.  I clarified the text more. My popen is happening in a thread, actually a thread in a thread, as it is described above.  Using setpgid does not work as I already tried that using preexec_fn, the result is the same.  Piping stdout can cause deadlocks on data sizes above 64k chunks in the stdout pipe.  Using wait/communicate with pipes would definitely cause a deadlock on a process spewing 1 GB of data.  Threading with signals is definitely causing my issues.

Comment: @whilster: [This example shows that there is no deadlock for data larger 64K](https://gist.github.com/zed/3b4606d811fcf6530795)